# How can I show numbers as percentages in CartoDB?

Tags: sql, carto, html

I would like to format numbers as percentages in cartodb. What are the best functions to display numbers with decimals, comma separators or percentages?

Answer (score 2):

There is no 'percentage' type so you need to use a `string`
You can do this by taking a numeric column and concatenating `||` with a `%`.

```
SELECT percent_column::text || '%' FROM table
```

You can also format the number first if you need, for example, multiply a decimal by `100` or `round` to sig digits,

```
SELECT round(percent_column * 100, 2)::text || '%' FROM table
```

For including commas, it is the same, you must turn numeric columns into strings. You could use this example,

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(76543210.98, '999G999G990D00')
```

Which was provided here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360752/how-to-set-thousend-separator-for-postgresql

or more generically

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(number_column, '999G999G990D00') FROM table
```