# How do I reformat numbers to only show a certain number of significant digits in CartoDB?

Tags: sql, carto

I need to round numbers that are in my table in CartoDB, so that in the Map visualization infowindows I only show results to two decimal digits rather than the long decimals that are currently showing.

I tried using `SELECT round(column,10,2) FROM table` as suggested on this webpage [How can I show numbers as percentages in CartoDB?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/87757/how-can-i-show-numbers-as-percentages-in-cartodb)

but the SQL query results in no records, and I get the following error:

`function round(double precision, integer) does not exist`

Is there another way to reformat the numbers so they display fewer decimals in the CartoDB infowindows without editing the source data?

Answer (score 4):

I was running into the same problem on CartoDB, and was able to find a solution based on some of the other answers here.

If you are running this query...

```
SELECT round(c, 2) FROM t
```

and get the error message `function round(double precision, integer) does not exist`

then the problem is that column c is double precision type rather than the numeric type that the round() function requires when there are two arguments.  (Somewhat confusingly, the round() function will accept a double precision type but only if there is just one argument.)

Although the solution from @user2033157 may work, you probably don't want to alter the entire table column just to run a query.  So here is a solution using CAST:

```
SELECT round( CAST(c as numeric), 2 ) FROM t
```

Comment: This worked for me and I think is a more complete solution than the top voted answer

Answer (score 2):

I think the syntax of your `ROUND()` function is incorrect. You are passing three inputs (`column`, `10`, and `2`) to the function, but it only needs two.

Try using `SELECT ROUND(column,2) FROM table`.

Comment: Unfortunately @Erika I tried that syntax and still get the same error that "function round(double precision, integer) does not exist".  I'm currently inputting the ROUND() function into the SQL window for the table in CartoDB.

Comment: I can only assume that CartoDB does not use the SQL ROUND() function, unfortunately... which seems strange. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

As Erica pointed out, you have one too many inputs in the syntax. However, the error message `function round(double precision, integer) does not exist` indicates that you actually used the correct syntax but have the wrong data type in the column to be rounded. The `ROUND` function requires the `numeric` data type, whereas the default number type on CartoDB is `dp`. So you need first convert the data type:

`ALTER TABLE name_of_table ALTER COLUMN 
column_to_be_rounded TYPE numeric`

After having done that, `SELECT ROUND(column_to_be_rounded,2) FROM table` should work.

If you just want to round to the nearest integer, you can skip the data type conversion and just use `ROUND(column_to_be_rounded)`.