# SQL in CARTO - round a function with two decimals in carto

Tags: carto, sql

I am try to round the expression below on carto but it  still returns no decimal places. The columns are 'number' type. I have also tried SELECT round( CAST(column as numeric), 2 ) suggested [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/107816/how-do-i-reformat-numbers-to-only-show-a-certain-number-of-significant-digits-in) but no decimals either.

```
SELECT name,

ROUND((COUNT(*) filter (where religion = 'Orthodox Christian')) *100/ (COUNT(*) ),2) as orth_chri

FROM dataset_1
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: The solution is : SELECT name,

ROUND((COUNT(*) filter (where religion = 'Orthodox Christian')) 100/ (COUNT() ),2) as orth_chri

FROM dataset_1 GROUP BY name

Answer (score 3):

The solution is to put ::numeric to change the data type

SELECT name,
 ROUND((COUNT(*) filter (where religion = 'Orthodox Christian')) 100/ (COUNT(*) ) ::numeric,1) as orth_chri

FROM dataset_1 GROUP BY name